# Can one not reference a CTE twice in a query in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression

I have a chain of CTEs, and at the end I want to select from the last one twice. Oracle lets me do either of the selects but not a union of both of them (even if I do "select * from (select union select)". The only thing I could narrow down the problem to was referring to "runinfo" in two selects, but that in and of itself is not the problem as Shannon shows.

```
WITH lastTen AS (
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT autobuild_id,  id, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY autobuild_id ORDER BY id DESC) as rank
      FROM runs
      WHERE status='FINISHED' AND type='FULL' AND build_failed in ('n', 'N'))
WHERE rank <= 10
),

recentAvg AS (
SELECT autobuild_id, avg(elapsed) avgtime
FROM runs
JOIN lastTen ON (runs.id = lastTen.id)
GROUP BY autobuild_id
),

runinfo AS (
SELECT autobuildid, runid, changelist, status, age
FROM (
    SELECT runs.autobuild_id autobuildid, runs.id runid, changelist, runs.status status, runs.create_date, a.avgtime,
       CASE WHEN status = 'RUNNING' THEN TO_NUMBER(sysdate - start_date)*86400 -- in seconds to compare to elapsed
            WHEN status = 'TO BE' THEN TO_NUMBER(sysdate - create_date) -- in days
       END AS age
    FROM runs
    LEFT JOIN recentAvg a ON (runs.autobuild_id = a.autobuild_id)
    )
WHERE (status = 'RUNNING' AND age > avgtime * 1.5)
   OR (status = 'TO BE' AND age > 1)
ORDER BY autobuildid, runid DESC
),

running AS (
SELECT autobuilds.id, name, runid, changelist, runinfo.status, age
FROM runinfo
JOIN autobuilds ON (runinfo.autobuildId=autobuilds.id)
WHERE runinfo.status='RUNNING'
),

tobe AS (
SELECT autobuildid, name, runid, changelist, status, age
FROM (SELECT autobuildid, name, runid, changelist, runinfo.status, age, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY autobuildid ORDER BY runid DESC) AS rank
     FROM runinfo
     JOIN autobuilds ON (runinfo.autobuildid=autobuilds.id)
     WHERE runinfo.status='TO BE')
WHERE rank=1
)

SELECT * FROM running
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tobe
```

Comment: You should really edit your question to include the example you gave, rather than stuffing it in a comment. Then you'll have all the space and formatting you need to illustrate your example. You can, as Shannon states, reference a CTE multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a difference between questions and comments.

Comment: Mostly it was "missing right parenthesis", but now, I'm embarassed to say, the whole thing is working. But I'm *SURE* that yesterday just adding the union caused the problem, while either of the union'ed selects worked on its own (though of course, I had to remove the one of "running" and "tobe" that I wasn't selecting from.

Many apologies.

Answer (score 10):

What is the simpliest query that doesn't work for you?

What is the complete error message?

Oracle does allow a CTE to be referenced twice, but I am not understanding what you are attempting:

```
SQL> with a as (select * from dual)
  2     , b as (select * from a)
  3     , c as (select * from b)
  4  select *
  5  from b, c
  6  where b.dummy = c.dummy;

D D
- -
X X
```

Comment: Although I do see that if I change your example, removing "c" and changing the final select to `select * from b union select * from b`, it works. So perhaps the double use of my runinfo cte is not the problem, but that's all I could come up with.

Comment: @Clarence: Are you trying to do a "recursive" CTE? `with CTE as (select ... from X union all select ... from x inner join CTE) select * from CTE`? That is not supported in Oracle prior to 11g R2. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/wnsql.htm#SQLRF50926. BTW, Oracle refers to the `with` clause as subquery factoring. Useful to know when search for Oracle specific information.

Comment: Nope, not recursive. The complete query is now in the question area. You can see that each query name references an earlier one or a table.